# Correction for jQuery rating system

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I want to build a 5 star rating system using jQuery, PHP and MySQL.
I am following [this](http://www.tutorialswindow.com/Web-Development/Javascript-tutorials/Creating-5-Star-Rating-System-Using-JQuery-PHP-MySQL-83.html) tutorial to make it, but I am getting an error in the jQuery part.
I am good at PHP and MySQL but have little knowledge about jQuery and Ajax.

jQuery code:

```
    $(function(){

$('.star').mouseover(function (){
var star = $(this).index() 1;
$(this).parent().css("background-position","0" - (32 * star) "px");
});

$('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
$(this).css("background-position","0 -" (32 * originalresult) "px");
}); 

});
```

HTML for this:

```
<div class="star-rating" id="rating1result0">
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
</div>
<div class="result">
<span style="color:green">0</span> (0)
</div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
.star-rating {
    width: 80px;
    height: 16px;
    float: left;
    background: url(_ls-global/images/layout-images/urating.png);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.star {
width:16px;
height:16px;
float:left;
}
.result {
float:left;
height:16px;
color:#454545;
margin-left:5px;
line-height:110%;
}
```

I tried changing the code like this but got an unexpected result.

```
    $(function(){

$('.star').mouseover(function (){
var star = $(this).index()+1;
$(this).parent().css("background-position","32px");
});

$('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
$(this).css("background-position","32px");
}); 

});
```

Please can somebody suggest to me what is wrong in the code?

Comment: i am sorry, but i don't know debugging java script. cant tell you, can you see any error in codes. thanks

Comment: Open your favorite browser and hit F12.  That will open developer tools.  Go to the script console and see if there are any errors showing up.

Comment: Well if I were you I would start by learning how to find the javascript error you're getting or writing javascript is going to be hard going for you. I use FireBug - a plugin for the FireFox browser.

Comment: Also note in Firefox the Error Console in `Tools > Web Developer > Error Console` is your friend.

Comment: Expected ')' at line where code is star) "px");

Comment: @S.L. Barth thanks for corrections in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally Got it.

```
    $(function(){

$('.star').mouseover(function (){
var star = $(this).index()+1;
var x =(32 * star);
$(this).parent().css("backgroundPosition","0% "  +(-x)+ "px");  
});

$('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
var y =(32 * originalresult);
$(this).css("background-position","0%" +(-y)+ "px");
}); 

});
```

hope this helps to others having same issue.

Comment: Your answer looks based on danish hashmis. You should upvote him. Just make sure to mark your answer as resolved.

Comment: actually i played around the codes and got it working, however i have up-voted danish hashmis answer for his time support.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

$('.star').mouseover(function (){
var star = $(this).index();
var newvalue =0-(32 * star);
$(this).parent().css("background-position",newvalue+" px");
});

$('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
var newvalue =0 -(32 * originalresult);
$(this).css("background-position",newvalue+"px");
}); 

});
```

Try this.

Comment: didn't work, hover not working properly, i am getting first 3 stars as green irrespect of hover position. thanks anyways

Comment: you need to add * 1 after index() function and try changing the value value according to the position u required.

Answer (score 0):

```
var star = $(this).index() 1;
```

what is the digit 1 supposed to do there? That's supposed to be the parse error.

Comment: var star = $(this).index()+1;  i tried like this and there is no parse error.